# Mount a Directory from one Server to set top box linux environment

Tags: linux

I run my build stored in linux server path eg user/aaditya/builds/build1/bin/ i have written an api which takes linux mount path as input
for example API- `takeimage,..//xyz.bmp` 
when i run it capture the image and stored in build1 folder but when i execute `takeimage,..//..//build2/` , no image is stored in build2 folder 
where path to build2 is  user/aaditya/builds/build2/ how to mount user/aaditya/builds/build2/
because API uses the linux system call to write the file

Answer (score 0):

In your two examples you are running your API like this:

takeimage ..//zyx.bmp

takeimage ..//..//build2/

I am guessing you run this from user/aaditya/builds/build1/bin/

In your first example you are providing your API the name of a file to save your image in.  In your second example you are only providing a directory path.  If the Build2 directory does not exist it could be producing an error.

Comment: My build2 directory exists,when i am calling api with build2 path i am getting segmentation fault

Comment: In your API, how are you storing that argument that is getting passed in?  Any chance you are overflowing an array?